# bash: Storing a pattern in a variable without the pattern being evaluated

Tags: bash, unix

I'm reading in a string from the command line, and storing it into a variable. The problem I'm having is that when I'm trying to store a pattern (for example *.cpp), the variable will end up holding the first match to that pattern if there's a match in my current directory, and the pattern if there's no match. What do I need to do in order to store a pattern into a string?

Question as code:

```
pattern=$1
#say $1 is *.cpp
#what do I need to do to $1 for pattern to hold *.cpp rather than the 1st match to *.cpp
```

EDIT: I did wrap $1 in quotes, but my result is the same as using no quotes at all.

Issue as a reproductable case:

```
#$1 is *.cpp
#!/bin/bash
pattern = "$1"
echo $pattern
```

pattern does not echo *.cpp, but the first file found that matches the pattern.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did use quotes, and it has the same exact effect as using no quotes at all (both return the 1st match).

Comment: how are you using `pattern` then...? you have not provided enough information to correctly evaluate the issue. Try to provide a reproduceable case.

Comment: Post has been edited.

Comment: the problem is that `*.cpp` is being evaluated by the shell **before** the script is run so `$1` is already expanded. You need to quote when running the script: `script '*.cpp'` to avoid the shell perform any expansions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some testing. It seems you need to quote both in the call *and* in the use in the script. I.e. in the script:

```
pattern=$1
echo "$pattern"
```

and then when calling the script:

```
./test.sh "*.cpp"
```

result:

```
*.cpp
```

Comment: that's how the shell works. if you execute `ls *.cpp`, the first argument of `ls` won't be `*.cpp`. it gets expanded to potentially many arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quote when passing parameter, so the exact string is preserved.

myscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1
```

Calling from cmdline:

```
# ./myscript.sh '*.cpp'
*cpp
```

Also the same result with backslash escaping:

```
# ./myscript.sh \*.cpp
*cpp
```